# rest, glassfish4 shiro enabled working sample

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish, shiro

I am new to javaee development. I am trying to build a javaee application in which rest services residing on Glassfish4 will be invoked by mobile clients. I came across apache shiro framework on the web for authentication and authorization. I would like to secure the services using shiro. 
For the time being I am trying to configure basic authentication with some hard coded users to gain confidence. My final goal is to move the user store to a database.

Following the apache shiro tutorial I configured my web.xml and shiro.ini.

1) But somehow the rest services are still open and I can invoke them without any password. is shiro.ini not getting loaded properly in my application ?

2) In future I will have multiple rest services from multiple applications, so I will need to configure shiro for all of them too ? Is there no way to handle authentication, authorization of multiple webapp using single shiro config ?

3) If you have a similar working sample please point me to that.

### Project location

URL : https://github.com/debashisgho/MyApp/

I can get the resource data without using any user/pwd

```
 http://localhost:8080/MyApp/rest/MyResource
```

I am sure that I have not configured it properly. Need help to find out what is missing.

Comment: Check your dependencies, specifically for **shiro-jersey**, the library that adds Shiro support to Jersey. Make sure you configure it properly (https://github.com/silb/shiro-jersey)

Comment: Thank you Baldy. I am using a javaee container glassfish to run my services. Do I still need to use the shiro-jersey ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell if in console you seeing any error or seeing shiro environment initialized succesfully.

can you try

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
```

instead of

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>configPath</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:shiro.ini</param-value>
     </init-param>
  </filter>
```

Comment: I re-deployed the application war after taking out the init-parm.
SEVERE: [admin-listener(8)] INFO org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader - Shiro environment initialized in 298 ms.
INFO: MyApp was successfully deployed in 1,172 milliseconds.
INFO: Initiating Jersey app...
SEVERE: PWC6117: File "..glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\MyApp\login.jsp" not found.
it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Got the basic auth and authorization working after changing the shiro config to the following
I will later on try to integrate this to DB. But this gives me confidence that Shiro will work.

```
[main]
authBasic = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter
[users]
# format: username = password, role1, role2, ..., roleN
root = secret,admin
guest = guest,guest
[roles]
#format; roleName = permission1, permission2, ..., permissionN
admin = *
[urls]
/api/** = authBasic
```

I did not get answer to my second question whether it is possible to configure a single shiro.ini for multiple webapp.